# Scala compiler producing nothing

Tags: scala, shell, ubuntu-16.04

I have installed Scala 2.11.6 on Ubuntu 16.04 and I'm trying to compile my first Hello World.

However, when I run `"scalac HelloWorld.scala"` on the command line, I receive no feedback (as if the operation was completed correctly), but no executable is produced in the folder.

My source file is:

```
object HelloWorld {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        println("Hello, world!")
    }
}
```

The command I am running is

```
scalac HelloWorld.scala
```

And it gives absolutelly no output.

I searched similar cases but I am unable to find anything. Am I missing something?

Comment: Do you get the expected output when you run `scalac -version`? Do you get error output if you run `scalac blah` (i.e. a non-existing file)?  And what happens when you run `scalac -verbose HelloWorld.scala`?

Comment: Running "scalac - version" returns "Scala compiler version 2.11.6 -- Copyright 2002-2013, LAMP/EPFL", "which scalac" returns "/usr/bin/scalac" while calling "scalac something" returns  "error: source file 'something' could not be found".

Comment: Hmm, it looks like the compiler is installed correctly.  The next thing I'd do is try to compile with the `-verbose` option and see if there are any errors or warnings in the copious output.

Answer (score 0):

The [scalac man page](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs-2.10.2/manual/html/scalac.html) explains:

> The scalac tool reads class and object definitions, written in the Scala programming language, and compiles them into bytecode class files.

```
$ls
HelloWorld.scala
$cat HelloWorld.scala
object HelloWorld {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        println("Hello, world!")
    }
}
$scalac HelloWorld.scala 
$ls
HelloWorld$.class   HelloWorld.class    HelloWorld.scala
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly, none of these files is created in my project folder. That's preciselly the problem.

Comment: Can you run `scalac -version` and `which scalac`/`where scalac` (if you're on Windows), and show that output?